# Renaming key-value-observing and key-value-coding tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, tag-synonyms

I would like to know if it's possible to rename the tags [key-value-observing](/questions/tagged/key-value-observing) and [key-value-coding](/questions/tagged/key-value-coding) with the protocols that actually define the behavior-- **NSKeyValueObserving** and **NSKeyValueCoding** respectively.

The former pair seems a bit vague while the second one indirectly specifies it's a protocol relevant to the Cocoa framework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, I don't think this is a good idea. The terms "key value observing" and "key value coding" are well-understood, and people know how to tag things with those as appropriate. I never refer to these concepts using the specific protocol names, so I see no reason to rename the tags to them.

I think this would cause more confusion than the way things are now.